# Unknown CSS collapsing margins, navbar/body vs. first div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margins

http://jsfiddle.net/cdecqyfs/

I'm trying to eliminate that apparently notorious gap between the navbar and the div below it.

I can't find the source of the margin through Chrome's developer tools (it just points me to the `<body>` tag), but I'm reasonably certain it's my div causing the issue, because when I delete the `<header>...<header>` contents entirely, there's still a 20px gap between the top and the body. HOWEVER, that gap size directly correlates with the value of `@navbar-bottom-margin` in Bootstrap's LESS files, so I'm sure BS is at play here.

I've tried `display:inline-block`, I've tried `margin:0 !important` on nearly every element on the page, numerous suggestions from the other times that this has been asked, and I'm slowly going insane over what should be such a simple issue to fix.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.masthead-text h1 { margin-top: 0; }` seems to be able to fix it. Use `padding` instead if it needs some spacings around.

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cdecqyfs/5/

I would also suggest to replace the below code with simple `padding` values too.

```
.masthead-text{
    position: relative;
    top: 140px;
}
```

Then it won't be necessary to reset the top margin on the h1.

**Updated Demo 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/cdecqyfs/7/

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I found the source in Type.less: `h1, .h1,
h2, .h2,
h3, .h3 {
  margin-top: @line-height-computed;
  margin-bottom: (@line-height-computed / 2);`  In this case, `@line-height-computed` was 20px.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit of a hacky workaround, but you can set the margin-bottom of the navbar to a negative value (in this case -20px), moving the content up and eliminating the gap.

http://jsfiddle.net/9LLo35kt/1/

```
/* The .masthead css doesn't need to be modified */
.masthead {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/LAtiqI6.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 400px;
}
    .masthead-text{
        position: relative;
        top: 140px;
        padding: 0 15%;
        color: #eee;
    }
    .masthead-text h1{
        font-size: 5em;
        text-shadow: -2px -2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .masthead-text h2{
        font-size: 2em;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

/* The important stuff: change this value from 0px to -20px */
.navbar { margin-bottom:-20px !important; }
```

Comment: I had considered doing something similar to the `margin-top` of the div. I'll probably end up doing this if the true culprit isn't identified, but it's probably going to bother me not knowing why it's behaving like this. Thanks for the tip! :)